# Read the next line of a file every time a function is called

Tags: c, file-io

I have a text file with numbers on each line. I want to write a function in C that reads in the file and returns the next number in the file every time the function is called.

For example if I have these numbers:

```
100 
200 
300 
400
```

and a function called get_number(), if I call get_number() it will return 100, if I call it again, it will return 200, etc.

This is what I've written so far but every time the function is called, it always goes back to the first number in the text file.

```
int * get_number()
{

    FILE* file = fopen("random_numbers.txt", "r");
    char line[256];

    if (file==NULL) 
    {
        perror ("Error reading file");
    }
    else
    {
        fgets(line, sizeof(line), file);
        printf("%s", line);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You'll want to use `ftell()` to get your current position in the file after the read and you'll want to use `fseek()` to seek to that position before every subsequent read.

Comment: You are leaking file descriptors here. To say the least.

Comment: You are reopening the file every time the function is called. Try doing that once by either doing it outside the method or by checking that file is NULL before opening the file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

here's a version that does exactly that :

```
 int * get_number(long* pos)
{

    FILE* file = fopen("random_numbers.txt", "r");
    char line[256];

    if (file==NULL) 
    {
        perror ("Error reading file");
    }
    else
    {
        fseek(file , *pos , SEEK_CUR);
        fgets(line, sizeof(line), file);
        printf("%s", line);
    }
    *pos = ftell(file);
    return 0;
}
```

and you call it from `main` like this

```
long pos = 0;
get_number(&pos);
```

or better yet use a static variable

```
 int * get_number()
{
    static long pos = 0;
    FILE* file = fopen("random_numbers.txt", "r");
    char line[256];

    if (file==NULL) 
    {
        perror ("Error reading file");
    }
    else
    {
        fseek(file , pos , SEEK_CUR);
        fgets(line, sizeof(line), file);
        printf("%s", line);
    }
    pos = ftell(file);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: shouldn't you close the file at the end of the function? and I also suspect if you call this function it will print the last line multiple times (this is just a hunch :) )

Answer (score 0):

It's a good idea to avoid opening a file repeatedly. Instead of opening the file every time you call the function, open it once, then pass a file pointer to the function each time you call it.

```
int * get_number(FILE *file)
{
    char line[256];

    fgets(line, sizeof(line), file);
    printf("%s", line);

    return 0;
}

int main()
{
    FILE *file = fopen("random_numbers.txt", "r");

    if (file == NULL) 
    {
        perror("Error opening file");
        return 1;
    }

    while (!feof(file))
    {
        get_number(file);
    }

    fclose(file);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Open the file in the calling function.
2. Pass the `FILE*` to `get_number`.
3. Return an `int` from `get_number`, not an `int*`.

Here's a modified `get_number`.

```
int get_number(FILE* file)
{
    // This is the core functionality.
    // You should add error handling code

    int number;
    int n = fscanf(file, "%d", &number);
    if ( n != 1 )
    {
       // Add error handling code.
    }

    return number;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is normal, because you open your file each time you call get_number(); (this is even worse because no fclose are called.
What you want maybe is giving a file descriptor at get_number(); in this way :

```
void get_number(FILE*  file)
{

    char line[256];

    if (file==NULL) 
        perror ("Bad descriptor given");
    else
    {
        if (fgets(line, sizeof(line), file) == NULL)
             perror("Fgets failed"); 
        else
             printf("%s", line);
    }
}
```

And what you want, outside your function, is to do the following :

```
FILE * file = fopen("random_numbers.txt", "r");
get_number(file); // 100
get_number(file); // 200
fclose(file);
```

I made your function void, because the return here is pointless. You could change that and use atoi and the return fonction.

Comment: It should be checking the return value of `fgets`.